# Google DialogFlow knowledge base connector not finding knowledge base in agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I used the code from the [DialogFlow docuumentation here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/knowledge-connectors#detect_intent_with_knowledge_base) in order to detect knowledge bases from my Spring boot app. I keep getting the following error:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Resource name 'NTAyODI1OTA4ODM1NDUwODgwMA' does not match 'projects/*/knowledgeBases/*'.
```

The resource name 'NTAyODI1OTA4ODM1NDUwODgwMA' is the one I took from the diagnostic info section in the Web UI from the DialogFlow section. The name of the Knowledge base is actually 'Billing'. I tried having that as the argument but am still getting the same error. Any ideas why? The knowledge base is clearly defined and I have been testing it out from the Web UI, but for some reason whenever I tried to interact with it externally I get the same error.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: I ended up avoiding using knowledge bases for now, so I didn't actually try your suggestion. Will do soon. Thank you for the help

Comment: Did you have any chance to check it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the knowledge Base ID from the Diagnostic Info, it is displayed as:

```
“Source”: “projects/<project_id>/knowledgeBases/<knowledgeBase_ID>”
```

So, I think that you have the correct `Knowledge Base ID`, either way the error that you are receiving is how you send the parameter.

The correct way to send the `Knowledge Base ID` parameter is: `projects/<project_id>/knowledgeBases/<knowledgeBase_ID>` instead of only sending the `Knowledge Base ID (NTAyODI1OTA4ODM1NDUwODgwMA)`.

In your case, you have to send the parameter as:

```
projects/<project_id>/knowledgeBases/NTAyODI1OTA4ODM1NDUwODgwMA
```

You only need to change the `<project_id>` to yours.